# Understanding LSTM Training and Validation Graph and their metrics (LSTM Keras) from the trained Model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I had trained a RNN/LSTM model. I would like to interpret my model results, after plotting the graph for Loss and accuracy (b/w training and Validation data set).

My objective is to classify the labels (either 0 or 1) if i provide only a partial input to the model. In such a way I have performed training.

**Train_Validate_Test_Split**

```html
Train 80% ; Validation 10 % ; Test 10%

X_train_shape : (243, 100, 5)
Y_train_shape : (243,)

X_validate_shape : (31, 100, 5)
Y_validate_shape : (31,)

X_test_shape : (28, 100, 5)
Y_test_shape : (28,)
```

**Model Summary**
[image]

**Model Graph**
[image]

**Question or Interpretation from the model results**

> Q 1 : What can I understand/interpret from loss and Accuracy graph ? 
>        How can i confirm whether the model trained properly for my data set or not ?
>
> Q 2 : Whether oscillations in both loss and accuracy, have some effect in model training ? (Or it is a normal behavior) If not, how
>   can I regularize my model without oscillations ?
>
> Q 3 : What can I interpret or understand from my metrics tabular
>   column ?
>   My Y_test accuracy is more when compared with Train & Validation accuracy, What can i interpret from this behavior ?

**Model Metrics**
[image]

Comment: Personally, I don't think your data is enough to explain your results. The first thing you need to do is to increase the amount of data.

Comment: As of now it is a difficult task.I have to work only with this data @giser_yugang

Comment: Could you kindly explain in detail, what are the effects if i have small data set ? Whether my data size used here is not sufficient for this model ?                       @giser_yugang

Comment: Generally speaking, too small training set will lead to model over-fitting. The number of training sets depends on specific models and scenarios. You can refer [How Much Training Data is Required for Machine Learning?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/much-training-data-required-machine-learning/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
But, what can i understand from my plot results ?
Whether the model gets trained properly or over fitting happens ? 
I believe that it provide a better results when I check for Classification report & Confusion matrix. So can i confirm that model learn properly ? Kindly comment on this scenario. @giser_yugang

Comment: From the graph, you can simply interpret if its training well or not. In simple terms, if the loss is reducing It means that its training well. However, `validation loss` plays an important role here to tell the extent of training, if the `validation loss` decreases with `training_loss`, then its moving towards minima. However if `validaion_loss` increase with decrease in `training_loss`, then your model is overfitting

Comment: Regarding oscillations, its normal as long as you find it reducing while smoothning, but it is better to prevent, which can be done with reducing `learning-rate`, which comes at the cost of more epochs required to train.